# How to find sub-directory exists in Linux machine using ruby

Tags: ruby, linux

I have a directory in Linux machine have sub directory's. need to identify sub directory and also need to identify is that directory is a symlink.

Below code not working for me
`File.directory?( "/usr/java/default/" )`
`File.symlink?( "/usr/java/default/" )`

Comment: Maybe `Dir.exists?("/usr/java/default")`

Comment: Dir.exists not working, getting below error.
in `load': undefined method `exists?' for Dir:Class (NoMethodError)

Comment: might be `exist?`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `File:ftype()` method. See
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/File.html#method-c-ftype for details.

Comment: not working for me getting below error 
`ftype': No such file or directory - /usr/java/default (Errno::ENOENT)

Comment: That message is indicating that `/usr/java/default` dir does not exist. What happens when you type `ls /usr/java/default` ?